# Connecting to database with php in c#

Tags: c#, php, mysql, database, post

I'm having problems connecting to a database through php when written in c#. I have a php script on a server with a wpf application just trying to write to the database.

```
 NameValueCollection UserInfo = new NameValueCollection();
 UserInfo.Add("username", username.Text);
 UserInfo.Add("password", password.Text);
 byte[] InsertUser = client.UploadValues("http://myaddress/phpfile.php", "POST",UserInfo);
```

Am I doing this right? If not, how should my php script look? What's the safest way? I have created an include file with database details.

Comment: There a several tutorials out there how to create a php code that receives parameters via post and queries a mysql database. Choose one and if you have a specific question, then ask that here.

Comment: I have been following tutorials, however, I am confused how to send the data sent to the PHP to the database and vice-versa. my PHP connects to the database.